# CodeIgniter 4 - How to Make Migration File in Modules\ContactUs NameSpace

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to generate and Run Migration File Into Custom NameSpace Modules\Contactus
in every module there was a full stracture like

-contactus

- config
- controllers
- database
- languages
- models
- views

I used this command

```
php spark make:migration --n Modules\\ContactUs
```

and

```
php spark make:migration --namespace Modules\\ContactUs
```

but all this commands not working correctly

$psr4 public property of the file app/Config/Autoload.php

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE             => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'                  => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules'   => ROOTPATH . 'Modules',
];
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Please, share the contents of the `$psr4` public property of the file `app/Config/Autoload.php`

Comment: hello steven i updated the question